# writing my first exploit in linux

Tags: linux, c, buffer

How can I modify the source code in the `func( )` so that the address to which the program returns after executing `func ()` is changed in such a manner that the instruction `printf("first print\n”)` is skipped. Use the pointer `*ret` defined in `func()` to modify the return address appropriately in order to achieve this.

Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func(char *str)
{
    char buffer[24];
    int *ret;
    strcpy(buffer,str);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
       printf("One argument needed.\n");
       exit(0);
    }

    int x;
    x = 0;
    func(argv[1]);
    x = 1;
    printf("first print\n");printf("second print\n");
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: hi sorry new to this. yea I'm new to linux and wanted to run this, but don't know how. any help, i will appreciate it

Comment: i need help modifying the code. thanks

Comment: in order to run the code you need to compile it. Search google for "compiling and running a C program in Linux"

Comment: thanks, i got that part. i had run it using the terminal in linux

Comment: now I don't know how to do part 1, so the first print is skipped

Comment: In that case I recommend editing your question so that you turn point 1 into a question that someone can answer. Some thing like; "How should I edit this code so that..." Leave the other two points out for a later question, as the answer to the first may solve the others.

Comment: i hope that now the question is clear. thanks all for the help

Comment: So what you are trying to do here is overwrite the return address located on the stack in the activation record that was created when calling `func()`. You have a buffer inside `func` that is automatically allocated on the stack as well. What you are going to be required to do is fill the buffer (its length is arbitrary) and then corrupt the stack such that when we return from the function, the return address is now invalidated (its now the return address of some other function). This is called a `buffer overflow` attack. You need to figure out exactly how many bytes to write to accomplish

Comment: .. this. Check the assembled code and also read up on activation records.

Comment: what the code should look like when it is modified? i have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As sherrellbc noted, a program's exploits are usually written without modifying its source code. But if you want, inserting these two lines into `func()` may do:

```
    ret = (int *)&str;  // point behind saved return address
    ret[-1] += 12;      // or however many code bytes are to be skipped
```